# Is it possible to read SharedPreferences held by another application?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to read the value of the Android Contacts application setting used to display contacts with phone numbers only.  (Accessible from the contact list, menu -> display settings, "only contacts with phone number").

According to the source code of the contacts application (see link below), that setting is stored in the SharedPreferences of the contacts application.

http://www.google.com/codesearch#J8HqCFe1rOo/src/com/android/contacts/ui/ContactsPreferencesActivity.java&q=ContactsPreferencesActivity.java&type=cs&l=146

Is it possible for my third party app to access that SharedPreference instance and read the value of that setting ?

Thanks a lot, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the SharedPreferences are not in private mode (which is the default setting) you can do this :
http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/25/getting-sharedpreferences-from-other-application-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of SharedPreferences
**Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple processes. This will be added later**
I think even then you need to have same signature